# Unity 3D AppStore link open issue

Tags: ios, iphone, unity-game-engine

I'm having a problem opening the AppStore via a button in Unity3D, either directly or through Safari.  I have the following code, but it doesn't work: Safari complains that the address is invalid.

The address seems to be ok when used directly in a browser: https://itunes.apple.com/us/developer/best-free-games-3d/id959029626

```
   public void OnClick()
    {
        Application.OpenURL ("https://itunes.apple.com/us/developer/best-free-games-3d/id959029626");

        Sound.instance.PlayButton();
    }
```

[image: Safari invalid address error message]

Answer (score 1):

Found super solution:

```
#if UNITY_IPHONE
Application.OpenURL("itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/us/developer/best-free-games-3d/id959029626");
#endif
```